# Getting multiple SQL Reports with HttpWebRequest - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I am trying to call multiple SQL Reporting Services Reports, get the .pdfs back, then append them together. I have no problems appending .pdfs, but I'm getting an error on the second report. Here's some example code:

```
    Dim httpReq As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(strLink), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
    Dim creds As New System.Net.NetworkCredential
    creds.Domain = "MyDomain"
    creds.UserName = "UserName"
    creds.Password = "Password"

    httpReq.Credentials = creds

    Dim httpResp As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(httpReq.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
    httpResp.Close()
    httpReq = Nothing
    httpResp = Nothing

    Dim SecondHttpReq As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(strSecondLink), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
    SecondHttpReq.Credentials = creds

    Dim SecondHttpResp As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(SecondHttpReq.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
```

When I try to create the second HttpResponse, I get a 401 Unauthorized error. When I check the SecondHttpReq object when it errors, I find that the Credentials property has been set back to Nothing. I've tried using a CookieContainer to no avail. I'd really rather not have to write a parent/sub report to get these together, so I'd like to hear other options. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Someone changed permissions on our report server without notifying anyone.